# how to add fields in ClientDetailsEdit screen Pos Odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to add a new field to the user creation and edition form from the pos, but it doesn't work.

```
<t t-name="ClientDetailsEdit" t-inherit="point_of_sale.ClientDetailsEdit" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//input[hasclass('client-name')]" position="after">
        <div class="client-detail">
            <div class='client-details-right mb-3' style="font-size: initial;">
        <input class="detail" name="numeroRUC"
                   t-on-change="captureChange" 
                   placeholder="Número de RUC ()" />
        </div>
    </xpath>
</t>
```